# 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'parse_arg'

Tags: python, argparse

I think my code belowis correct. It attempts to make a 'checkRoot' option possible from command line. But even the simplest code does not work, with

```
'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'parse_arg'
```

The code is shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":

    message='[setting] ... '
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=message)

    parser.add_argument('--checkRoot' , required=False, action='store_true',default=False)

    results = parser.parse_arg()
    if results.checkRoot:
        print "root-checking"
```

Where do you find the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Becasue the correct function name is `parse_args()`, with an 's':

```
results = parser.parse_args()
```